# different types for rxjs WebSocketSubject based on request/response (next msg type, subscribe msg type), but only one generic is allowed

Tags: typescript, generics, types, websocket, rxjs

i'm working with `webSocket` from rxjs, and having an issue with the generic type argument.

the websocket API documentation states that request and response messages have different properties, but the generic for `WebSocketSubject` only accepts one type.

so we have something like:

```js
import { webSocket } from "rxjs/webSocket";

const subject = new webSocket<MessageType>('wss://something');

subject.subscribe({
    error: err => {
        throw err;
    },
    next: msg /* this is of type MessageType, but the actual object is not the same type as what is input into `subject.next` */ => {
        console.log(msg); // outputs something like: { anotherProperty: "anotherValue" }
    },
    complete: () => {
        done();
    }
}); 

// but this argument is also of type MessageType
subject.next({
    testProperty1: "test value 1"
});
```

the problem is then that the type of `msg` in the `next` property of the `subscribe` method but also `subject.next` is the same, while the documentation specifies differing types (the objects have different properties) for input and output messages.

now of course it would be possible to use `any` or create a union type with optional parameters in order to make things work, but it would be more ideal to be able to specify one type for input messages and another for output messages. can this be achieved easily with the rxjs implementation of `webSocket` or do i need to write a wrapper or something in order to make this more clean?

ideally what i'd like to do would be something to the effect of the following (although of course i don't currently see that it's possible):

```js
const subject = new webSocket<RequestMessageType, ResponseMessageType>('wss://something');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two types in question...

1. The generic when you invoke `webSocket<T>()`
2. The value being passed into next `.next<T>()`

...they are the exact same type.

The generic you're defining at instantiation `T` is the message type that will be received from the web socket upon subscription.

`WebSocketSubject` is an extension of a `Subject`, which includes methods like `.next()`. This mean `WebSocketSubject.next()` does the same thing as `Subject.next()`, it emits the next value of type `T` for all RxJS subscribers. This is why the `.next()` method has the same `T` generic.

The way `WebSocketSubject` lets you send messages (which is of type `any`) to the WS is when you declare your public observables that will be for subscribers.

```
const wsSubject = webSocket<MessageType>('wss://something');

const wsMessages$ = wsSubject.multiplex(
  () => {} , // send message to WS server to start 
  () => {} , // send message to WS server to stop 
  (message) => true // filter messages by condition
);
```

These start and stop messages are automatically executed as subscribers start or end subscriptions to `wsMessages$`.

Reference: https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/WebSocketSubject

Comment: yes, in the documentation they are the same type. but in the implementation of the websocket resource that i'm using, they are of different types, thus we have a different behaviour at runtime than is expected based on the documentation / passing a single generic

Comment: OK - so using the `.multiplex` method instead of `.next` works. i guess the point of confusion that i had was that using `.next` with the subscription message worked if the type was valid (the server would respond as predicted), but that message was of a different type than the one the server sent. thanks for the help!